# Как я могу перезагружать маршрутизатор при потере интернет соединения?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, router

Как мне это сделать имея сервер с накатаной Ubuntu в локальной сети.

Роутер: tenda 4g630

Comment: Есть как минимум два очевидных варианта: простой и дешёвый. Причём "дешёвый" дёшев только в смысле затрат на оборудование (они нулевые) но никак не в плане затрат времени. Простой вариант заключается в покупке какой-нибудь управляемой розетки с последующим дёрганием питания роутера через неё, например, по SNMP. Дешёвый состоит в написании скрипта, который будет по HTTP (других вариантов у этой модели вроде нет) заходить на роутер и давать ему команду перезагрузки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте web-браузер вашего сервера для удалённого доступа к интегрированному сервису роутера Tenda 4g630. В адресной строке введите адрес устройства (заводская настройка по умолчанию - 192.168.0.1), на приглашение авторизоваться введите имя: admin (и пароль - admin, если заводские настройки не менялись). Для перезагрузки служит вкладка Tools/Reboot. Проверьте настройки удалённого доступа к устройству на вкладке Advanced/Remote Web Management: отметку в checkbox-е "Enable", ip-адрес (вашего сервера) и порт для удалённого управления. При необходимости операцию удалённой перезагрузки роутера можно оформить программно отдельной утилитой.